# Clustered data and multiclass classification with GPBoost

Tags: classification, mixed-model, multi-class, cluster-sample

Is it possible to do multiclass classification using GPBoost?
For example when we have **3 or more classes** (e.g. specie A/ specie B/ specie C) from a **clustered data** set (e.g. several measurements over the same subject or clustered by region/city/state).

I understand that in GPBoost we can set `likelihood="binary"`, but does it works when there are three classes or more?

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think they have implemented gpboost for multiclass outcomes yet (surely not up to June 2022, see [this](https://github.com/fabsig/GPBoost/issues/67)).